# How do I move data between two different Redux slices?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using the latest (as of today) version of React+ React-Redux.
When I start my app, I load a list of data I need to store in a slice that is used for one purpose. For this example, a list of table names and their fields.
I also have a slice that manages UI state, Which needs **only** the table names to create a sub-menu.
The list of tables with all it's data is loaded into slice **tree** and I need to copy just the table names into a slice called **UI**.

I am not very clear on the best way (or the right way) to move data between two sibling slices.

Comment: This is what redux connectors are for. They connect disparate sets of higher order state and prop data into that used by a component. So for your menu component that renders the submenu, make a connector that maps the table data from the other slice into a prop. Redux docs are pretty straightforward with how to do this.

Comment: Copying data from one slice to another is not a normal thing to do. I would just create a selector function that extracts what you need from the tree slice and call it in the components that need the table names.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to reach a state of sibling slice:

1. `getState` in dispatch(action)
   create an action for UI slice for your purpose, getState returns whole store object, [see](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction)

```js
export const setUIElements = (payloadOfTheUIDispatch) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { sliceNameOfTheTable } = getState();
  const tableData = sliceNameOfTheTable;
  // ... update data as you need:
  dispatch(actionThatUpdatesUISlice(data));
}
```

then read the state that is `actionThatUpdatesUISlice` updates. Do the reading in your component with `useSelector`.

2. use `useSelector` in the component which creates submenu. Read from both `tableSlice` and `uiSlice`:

```js
  const tableData = useSelector(state => state.tableData);
  const uiData = useSelector(state => state.ui);

  // create submenu here
  // example: 
  const subMenu = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!tableData || !uiData) return null;
    return tableData.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>);
  },[tableData, uiData]);
```

3. If you are performing some kind of expensive calculation to create data for the submenu in ui slice, you can use `createSelector`, but the first two method is best, if you do not perform any expensive calculation:

```js
export const selectSubMenuItems = createSelector(
  state => state.ui,
  state => state.table,
  (uiData, { stateNameOfTableDataInTableSlice }) => {
    const { stateNameFromUISliceThatYouNeed } = uiData;
    const expensiveCalculation = differenceBy(
      stateNameFromUISliceThatYouNeed,
      stateNameOfTableDataInTableSlice.map(item => item.name),
      'id',
    );
    return expensiveCalculation;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took eventually was to add a reducer to the second slice that catches the same action as the first slice, hence both get the same payload at the same time. With no dependencies on each other.
But, if I could solve this with a simple selector (like the comment in my questions suggests, it would have been preferred).

first slice:

```
const SliceA = createSlice({
  name: "sliceA",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase("a1/menueData/loaded", (state,action) => {
           //do what I want with action.payload
    }
  }
}



// in a different file


const SliceB = createSlice({
  name: "sliceB",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase("a1/menueData/loaded", (state,action) => {
           //do what I want with action.payload, which is the same one as 
           //in reducer A above
    }
  }
}
```